# Jquery Mobile button looks weird

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

Hi so questions explains it all my button looks weird I'll show you a picture so you know what I mean.

[image]

```
<button type="submit" 
        data-icon="false" 
        class="ui-nodisc-icon"  
        data-theme="a" 
        data-inline="true" 
        name="loginButton"  
        id="loginButton" value="submit">Login</button>
```

I'm using jquery-mobile themeroller and this is what I get..

Comment: You want to change it?? what is the problem??

Comment: And what is your question exactly? How do you want your button to display?

Comment: Well my button is supposed to be the grey part I don't know why there is the default looking html button inside my button.

Comment: which version jQuery mobile?

Comment: Post the code or a link to where you've got this up so we can see. It looks to me like you have a div or something with the grey styling, and the button itself is unstyled.

Comment: Use `input type=submit` instead of `button` tag, or use anchor `a`.